# Numpy covariance matrix implementation

Tags: python, numpy

For a project I'm implementing the CSP algorithm in which I need a covariance matrix. In multiple sources of literature I found the following expression for computing a covariance matrix: (X times X^{T}) / trace(X times X^{T}) for some matrix X which I implemented:

```
covariance = np.matmul(A, np.transpose(A)) / (np.matmul(np.dot(A, np.transpose(A))))
```

From a mathematical standpoint it makes sense in my computations but this expression simply does not give me the same result as the standard numpy implementation np.cov(A). My question is if the expression I found is actually a valid computation for covariance matrices?

https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0125039#pone.0125039.ref006 gives the mathematices under the section materials and methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your formula. Let me do it step by step

First define a matrix `A` with two variables and five observations each. Use random numbers for demonstrattion

```
np.random.seed(23423)
n_obs = 5
n_var = 2
A = np.random.normal(0.0,1.0, size=(n_var,n_obs))
A
```

output

```
array([[ 1.51978937,  0.56200696, -0.17770035,  0.01628744,  2.45856104],
       [-1.25514739, -0.17201069, -0.42486057, -0.09215201, -0.21674946]])
```

Second, *we need to center the variables*, ie subtract their mean. `A0` will be a centered version of A

```
A0 = A - A.mean(axis=1).reshape(n_var,-1)
A0
```

output

```
array([[ 0.64400048, -0.31378193, -1.05348924, -0.85950145,  1.58277214],
       [-0.82296337,  0.26017334,  0.00732345,  0.34003201,  0.21543456]])
```

Now we can calculate the covariance, using a version of your formula (only the numerator, but divide by the number of observations -1)

```
(A0 @ A0.T)/(n_obs-1)
```

output

```
array([[ 1.21673642, -0.14265396],
       [-0.14265396,  0.22676158]])
```

Let's compare this to `np.cov`:

```
np.cov(A)
```

output

```
array([[ 1.21673642, -0.14265396],
       [-0.14265396,  0.22676158]])
```

The two match as promised.

Your original formula looks more like a *correlation* not *covariance*; but it also has multiple issues (only one argument to `matmul` where it needs two, lacks the centering step etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! I'm simply using the formula supplied by the source of which I put the link. Do you happen to have any idea why it's used there in that context?

Comment: Looking at the blurb above eq (3) it is 'the covariance matrix of the **band pass-filtered** signal XC,i' (emphasis mine) so it seems that applying the band-pass filter to X does that normalization by `tr` to the covariance matrix

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @BasCarpentero No problem! If the answer helped consider accepting it, per the site guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers